# Why is Android service being reset after unbind was called?

Tags: android, service, unbind

In my project android service is communication with serial device and it is being started when BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast is received. Occasionally I want to bind to the service for persistent connection. After unbind the service seems to restart, which is not very desirable when communication with serial device.

In Service:

```
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
  Log.d(TAG, "onBind");
  return messenger.getBinder();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
  ...
  return START_STICKY;
}
```

In Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onStart()
{
  super.onStart();
  bindService(new Intent(this, BMWiService.class), serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop()
{
 super.onStop();
 if (serviceBound)
  {
    unbindService(serviceConnection);
    serviceBound = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: start your service just before binding

Comment: It is being started when android is booting up. I have also tried to start it prior binding, but service is still being restarted after unbind.

Comment: strange,  it shouldn't be restarded,  try for testing to remove BOOT_COMPLETED intent filter and see what happens,  btw you explicitly call startService before binding or use auto create flag?

Comment: dont use Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE, call startService explicitly

Comment: I wasn't fully aware of what BIND_AUTO_CREATE flag did other than startService if it is not running. As I have just read, it starts service and keeps it alive until clients are bound. Post as an answer for rep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start your service by calling startService() just before binding